# sdate Parameter has no default value

Tags: delphi-2010

I keep on getting that my sdate got no Value.

```
procedure TForm1.Button12Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  sdate : string;
begin
  sDate := inputbox('Date', 'Enter Date', '');
  CDQuery.Active := False;
  CDQuery.SQL.Text := 'Select Ownername, DateOfBirth from Owner_Table where DateOfBirth < Datevalue(sdate)';
  CDQuery.Active := True;
end;
```

Comment: [What is the exact error message? Is it a compiler error or a runtime error? In what line does it occur?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You did not concatenate sDate with your SQL statement. You just put it inside the string.
You need to do something like this:

```
  sDate := inputbox('Date', 'Enter Date', '');
  CDQuery.Active := False;
  CDQuery.SQL.Text := 'Select Ownername, DateOfBirth from Owner_Table where DateOfBirth < DateValue(:sdate)';
  CDQuery.Parameters.ParamByName('sdate').Value := sDate;
  CDQuery.Active := True;
```

Comment: welcome .. please mark it as accepted answer to improve your acceptance rating and encourage others to answer your questions in the future.